# ADFS 3.0 Service Unavailable in some circumstances

Tags: adfs

according to the blog [How To Install ADFS](http://blogs.technet.com/b/rmilne/archive/2014/04/28/how-to-install-adfs-2012-r2-for-office-365.aspx) (Part 1 + 2), I did setup a ADFS Server and a ADFS Proxy, both based on Windows Server 2012 R2.

I can achieve the federationmetadata.xml page both from internal and external network regardless whether using a domain user or using a workgroup user. So far, so good.

But trying to achieve the /adfs/idpInitiatedSignOn.hml page only succeeds, if I connect from the internal network as a domain user. Trying to access this page failes with HTTP error 503 (Service Unavailable), if I want connect from external network. The same issue occurs if I try to connect from internal network as a non-domain user.

Unfortunately there are no entries in the event log referring to this issue. Has anyone an idea what happens in my environment?

Regards

Enrico

Comment: Is this a new install? If yes, you could reinstall the environment and see if it still occurs. Else, if you are keen to troubleshoot it, start with using the diagnostic module from https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/AD-FS-Diagnostics-Module-8269de31

Comment: I think it's just a question of using https instead of http. That worked for me.